# implicit declaration of function 'asprintf'

Tags: c, compiler-errors, gcc-warning

I created a program that would help convert my PHP code to a runnable c file, so I can use the PHP functions. The program runs perfectly on my system(Windows 10) but fails to run on my colleagues' systems(Windows 10 also). n my header, I created my own asprintf because the function does not exist on windows.

My asprintf.h

```
#ifndef ASPRINTF_H
#define ASPRINTF_H

#if defined(__GNUC__) && ! defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
#define _GNU_SOURCE /* needed for (v)asprintf, affects '#include <stdio.h>' */
#endif
#include <stdio.h>  /* needed for vsnprintf    */
#include <stdlib.h> /* needed for malloc, free */
#include <stdarg.h> /* needed for va_*         */

/*
 * vscprintf:
 * MSVC implements this as _vscprintf, thus we just 'symlink' it here
 * GNU-C-compatible compilers do not implement this, thus we implement it here
 */
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define vscprintf _vscprintf
#endif

#ifdef __GNUC__
int vscprintf(const char *format, va_list ap)
{
    va_list ap_copy;
    va_copy(ap_copy, ap);
    int retval = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, ap_copy);
    va_end(ap_copy);
    return retval;
}
#endif

/*
 * asprintf, vasprintf:
 * MSVC does not implement these, thus we implement them here
 * GNU-C-compatible compilers implement these with the same names, thus we
 * don't have to do anything
 */
#ifdef _MSC_VER
int vasprintf(char **strp, const char *format, va_list ap)
{
    int len = vscprintf(format, ap);
    if (len == -1)
        return -1;
    char *str = (char*)malloc((size_t) len + 1);
    if (!str)
        return -1;
    int retval = vsnprintf(str, len + 1, format, ap);
    if (retval == -1) {
        free(str);
        return -1;
    }
    *strp = str;
    return retval;
}

int asprintf(char **strp, const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    int retval = vasprintf(strp, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return retval;
}
#endif

#endif // ASPRINTF_H
```

My main.c

```
#include "asprintf.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char _binary_script_php_start;
extern char _binary_script_php_end;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // EXTRACT OUR RESOURCE OBJECT INTO /tmp/test.php
    char *p = &_binary_script_php_start;
    FILE *fp = fopen("/tmp/test.php","wb");
    while ( p != &_binary_script_php_end ) {
        fputc(*p++,fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    // NOW READ IN OUR STANDARD ARGUMENTS AND LAUNCH OUR COMMAND
    int i = 1;
    char *cmd = "php /tmp/test.php";
    char *s = NULL;
    asprintf(&s, "%s",cmd);
    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        asprintf(&s, "%s \"%s\"",s,argv[i]);
    }
    // concatf("%s",cmd);
    // for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    //     concatf("%s \"%s\"",s,argv[i]);
    // }
    // concatf(&s, "%s",cmd);
    // for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    //     concatf(&s, "%s \"%s\"",s,argv[i]);
    // }
    system(s);
    free(s);
    unlink("/tmp/test.php"); // comment me out for debugging if you want
}
```

I was able to recreate their error by creating a new header file and changing the name of the function. so when they get:

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'asprintf'
> [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]    29 |     asprintf(&s, "%s",cmd);

I get:

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'concatf'
> [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]    29 |     concatf(&s, "%s",cmd);

Which is not making sense to me, I know for this to work, the function should be declared before the main function and that is already being done. I know I have to define _GNU_SOURCE which is being handled in my header file. Are there rules I am not adhering to? If so why would it work in my environment and not my colleagues'?

To be able to run this create a PHP file called script.php and run the following commands:

```
php:
    ld -r -b binary script.php data.o
exe:
    gcc main.c data.o -o runme
```

if working properply ./runme should run the php file.

Kindly find the source code here: https://github.com/Sammiiie/C_php_http

Comment: Please provide all required code in your question. External links can go stale making your question worthless for future visitors. Or as it seems they can already be invalid now.

Comment: Both messages indicate that you did not include the required headers. Also what does "In my header, I created my own asprintf" mean? Function definitions should not be in headers. Only declarations should go there.

Comment: @Gerhardh I have edited and provided code samples. I have included, headers appropriately. By my header I mean the header file I created and asprintf is C function found on linux, so in other to use it on windows I had to recreate the function.

Comment: You really should not *define* (implement) functions in header files. Think about what might happen if you include `asprintf.h` is multiple source files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have made that correction in my project. Yet to solve my error.

Comment: You should put function and variable definitions in C files, not in headers.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes I have made that correction in the project already. But error still remains and I am still awaiting an explanation on why it works on my environment but not on others,

Comment: @Gerhardh after moving the function to its own .c file, I get an undefined reference error. but the same changes works well on my environment.

Answer (score 1):

These functions, optional by standard, are defined in the document: **ISO/IEC TR 24731-2**.

They need to be explicitely enabled defining the constant `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__` before including the header `stdio.h`.

From **ISO/IEC TR 24731-2**,**5.1.1 Standard headers**:

> The functions, macros, and types defined in Clause 5 and its subclauses **are defined by their respective headers if _*STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2* _ is defined** as a macro which expands to the integer constant 1 at the point in the source file where the appropriate header is included.

I.e.

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__  1
#include <stdio.h>
....
```

In your case, to enable it only for **non** MS compilers, you may write:

```
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__  1
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
....
```

Comment: I have tried defining __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__ in asprintf.h and it did not work.

Comment: Have you compiled it under GCC? MS doesn't care of the definition because it doesn'exist in MS compilers.

Comment: Yes I have been using GCC to compile,

Comment: Try defining `#define __GNU_VISIBLE 1`. For some versions of GCC where `_GNU_SOURCE ` doesn't works it should expose the definitions.

Comment: And be sure that `_GNU_SOURCE ` and `__GNU_VISIBLE` gets really defined.